# How should I add tab view in swift os x

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, tabview

How should I add a tab view and switch tab view in tabViewController ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let newItem: NSTabViewItem = NSTabViewItem(identifier: "abc")
    let tv: NSTextView = NSTextView(frame: NSZeroRect)
    newItem.view?.autoresizesSubviews = true
    newItem.view?.addSubview(tv)
    newItem.label = "Untitled"
    //tabView.addTabViewItem(newItem)
    //tabView.selectTabViewItem(newItem)
    //tabView.insertTabViewItem(newItem, atIndex: 3)
    //tabView.selectFirstTabViewItem(IspViewController)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

We should set `NSViewController` to created `NSTabViewItem`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let newItem: NSTabViewItem = NSTabViewItem(identifier: "abc")
    newItem.label = "Untitled"
    // "tvcontroller" is in storyboard
    newItem.viewController = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("tvcontroller") as? NSViewController

    addTabViewItem(newItem)
}
```